# How to show a large table using JQuery Mobile?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

We are trying to show a large table (more than 50 columns and 100 rows) using jQM in a web application for iPAD and desktop users.

JQM works fine for us, but in our first possibility (a pure html table in a division), the vertical scroll works fine even having a floating footer, but the table was truncated horizontally, the horizontal scroll is disabled. 
Then we tried to use differents experimental scrollviews ([JQM Scrollview](http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/scrollview-direction.html)) but it doesn't work at all if we create the table via DOM.

Any suggestion? Which is the better way to show large tables in JQM? Any tested grid to use with jQM?

**EDIT:**
We added an example here. http://oterrada.webatu.com/test.html

Comment: Could you add some examples? Link to a demo or something?

Comment: Hmm some testing http://jsfiddle.net/xQ9db/1/ and I think for a mobile device you're going to run into some issues. IMHO I would rethink the layout +1

Comment: @PhillPafford, thanks, you can check an example now that we want to do. One table is in the html and the other is created when you push the button with DOM.

Comment: It's not really documented but could you try: $('#dataContainer').scrollview(); after $('#catalog').trigger('create');

Comment: thanks @PhillPafford Now the example works fine!! It seems that $('#catalog').trigger('create') is not necessary but it only works the first time you push the button, some property is lost when it redo the table. We will check that or empty the table by other way. Thanks again.

Comment: @PhillPafford, I add your solution and I close the question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really documented but could you try:

```
$('#dataContainer').scrollview();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try my work-in-progress [tableview](http://www.stokkers.mobi/jqm/tableview/demo.html) plugin I did using filaments [responsive table patterns](http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/rwd-table-patterns/)

Click on the gear icon far right.

This opens a custom-jqm-select where the user can decide, which columns he wants to be visible. All columns without class "persist" can be toggled this way. There should be enough info in the source code to get you started. A lot is taken from JQM listview (filtering, inset, ...), so you should be able to find your way around if you are familiar with JQM.

Comment: Any more information regarding your "tableview" plugin for jQuery Mobile?  I'm writing a webapp for iPad & table filtering per column is important. The DataTables library can be used, but it's not using the jQMUI like your plugin does.  The main version I don't want to use DataTables is because it uses jQueryUI for styling and isn't compatible with jQMobile's UI (the last time I tried.)

Comment: Thought the same, but adding all the functionality dataTables offers was way over my head. Basically I have two work-in-progress versions of tableview. One version is "plain" = without any functionality, the other version is "enhanced" = uses dataTables, BUT I started replacing the dataTables JQueryUI with my own JqueryMobile UI for the reason you mentioned. I got it to work for my purposes, but it's far from done.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is adding $('#dataContainer').scrollview();  after populate the table but be carefully if the division has de data-scroll="true" because if it has it, the scroll doesn't apply correctly.